# Pulling a number from a config for sleep

Tags: python, sleep

Basically I'm trying to pull a string input into a config as the sleep timer. 
I keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 50, in <module>
    sleep(sleep_time)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

This is the code I am using. Is there a better way to do this? Basically I want to be able to input a sleep time into a config after it's made into an exe.

```
sleep_time=config.get('settings', 'SleepTime')
sleep(sleep_time)
```

Comment: Maybe use `sleep(int(sleep_time))`?

Answer (score 0):

Like the traceback says, you need to convert the variable into an `int` before passing it to `time.sleep`.

You can do this using the `int` built-in, which will take a string and convert it to an integer. You can also provide a second number to change the base of the conversion, the default base is 10.

```
myint = int("10")        # myint == 10
myint = int("1a", 16)    # myint == 26
```

I'm assuming `SleepTime` is the name of the variable you're using for the default sleep time. Personally I would write the function call out like this;

```
sleep_time = config.get("settings")
if sleep_time is not None:
    sleep_time = int(sleep_time)
else:
    sleep_time = SleepTime

sleep(sleep_time)
```

But you may wish to do something like this to improve readability;

```
sleep_time = int(config.get("settings", "1")) # sleep for 1 second by default
sleep(sleep_time)
```